# scoping in R, and dealing with 'with'

Tags: r, scoping

In R, there are lots of situations where `with` seems to be used to help you write shorter code; however, this masks existing symbols like local variables and function parameters. Is there any way to refer to them without renaming them so they don't clash with your data?

For instance, in this frame, I've got a `state` column;

```
df <- data.frame(
  label=c("a", "b", "c"),
  state=c("off","on","off"))
```

I can write a filtering function with a `.state` parameter, and the filter works;

```
instateWorks <- function(.state) {
  subset(df, df$state == .state)
}

# correct - 1 observation for "b"
onWorks <- instateWorks("on")
```

but if I give my function a sensible parameter name, there's a problem and the symbol `state` seems to refer to the data frame's column;

```
instateFails <- function(state) {
  subset(df, df$state == state)
}

# fails - all 3 observations
onFails <- instateFails("on")
```

Is there any way to qualify that `state` is supposed to mean the parameter, to make the script work as expected?

---

Edit - to clarify why 'with' and 'eval' are the issue I'm struggling with, consider this code;

```
df <- data.frame(
  label=c("a", "b", "c"),
  state=c("off","on","off"))

with(df, state == "on")
# FALSE TRUE FALSE

state <- on
with(df, state == state)
# TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In the last `with` statement, I'm looking for a way to express 'tell me which rows have the 'state' variable in DF has the same value as the 'state' variable defined on the line above.

Without this ability, I can't write a function with a parameter called the same thing as the name of a column.

Comment: use this instead of subset: instateFails <- function(state) df[df$state == state,]

Comment: From `help(subset)` -  *Warning

This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.*

Comment: I'm only using subset because it illustrates the problem with 'with'. The same problem occurs in, say, dplyr where I can't say `filter(df, state == state)`. It's a general issue with passing expressions to functions, which `eval` in an environment different from the calling function.

Comment: In `dplyr` you should use `filter_()` inside functions (note the `_`).  The package was written with standard-eval versions for this purpose.  If you have a question about `with()` please edit because `with()` isn't used in `subset()`.

Comment: Both 'subset' and packages in the hadleyverse are going to have non-standard evaluation "surprises".

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff updated the question! thanks

Comment: You would have to use something like `with(df, state == get("state", globalenv()))` to go and get `state` from the global environment.  But as you can see, we've defeated the purpose of shorter code since now we can just do `df$state == state`.  Plus it can get hairy using `get()`

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff -- the environment() call actually gives me what I'm looking for. I can do ; 
`instateFails <- function(state) { args <- environment(); subset(df, state == args$state) }` to differentiate -- create a variable called args (or whatever) which lets me refer to the variables in the calling function from inside the filter expression. Should work everywhere, and it's a single-line workaround...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @HaddE.Nuff, I came up with this;

```
instateFails <- function(state) {
  args <- environment()
  subset(df, state == args$state)
}
```

capture the current environment before you make the call, which gives you a way to refer to all the locals in the calling function. Then refer to the environment variable inside the filter expression.